# Crystal report app crash VS2010 crpe32.dll

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

good evening: I face a problem with crystal report  I use VS2010 and SP1 CR  with Microsoft sql server 2008  OS:win7

the project use the crystal report to print a bill for a customer..the program configure with a POS printer when i run the app it works and print sometimes 1 to 5 bill then  the crystal report cause app crash  fault model name: crpe32.dll and the pogram hang. when i try to debug the .exe it seems that the crystal report try to access a protected memory.
I don`t know why this happen and how to fix this error or how can i know what is the code that cause this.
any help please ????

Comment: Same error with me.I need a solution too.

Comment: See my answer in another thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33569720/printing-multiple-report-using-crystal-report-crash-applcation/69504909#69504909