# Printing multiple report using Crystal Report crash applcation

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, crystal-reports

I have a WinForms Application (.net 4.0, x86) with Crystal Reports (13.0.15). I want to print multiple documents using Crystal Reports (without seeing them on Report Viewer - directly on printer).

```
foreach (var document in documents )
{
  ReportDocument report=GenerateReport(document.id);
  report.PrintToPrinter(printerSettings, pageSettings, false);
}
```

Everytime it prints 48 reports and on 49th print I've got exception `System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception The handle is invalid Void OnStartPrint(System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventArgs)`

I tried another set of documents but I still have exception on 49 print.

I tried to change PrintJobLimit to over 9000 but it doesn't help.

Next I tried to dispose report after print:

```
foreach (var document in documents )
{
  using (ReportDocument report=GenerateReport(document.id))
  { 
    report.PrintToPrinter(printerSettings, pageSettings, false);
  }
}
```

But now program crashes before print 28th report and I cannot catch exception (program stop working). Only in Event Viewer is information about Application Error (`Faulting module name: ntdll.dll`). 
I tried different things (and combination of them):

```
    report.Close();

    report.Dispose();

    report=null;
```

even `GC.Collect()` after print but it still doesn't work.
Anybody has a solution?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like when `report.PrintToPrinter` returned, the underlying operation sometimes went on. You need to keep `reportDocument` alive for a few more time, instead of let it go out of scope and GC collection kick in.

My solution is to put them into a delayed queue and `Close` them later, something like:

```
foreach (var document in documents )
{
    ReportDocument report = GenerateReport(document.id);
  
    report.PrintToPrinter(printerSettings, pageSettings, false);
    Task.Run(async () => {
        // keep report alive for extra 60 secs
        await Task.Delay(60 * 1000);
        report.Close();
        report.Dispose();
    })
  
}
```